# /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1

Tags: go, gcc, tdlib

trying to run a golang program, but I receive the error of gcc as:

command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
compilation terminated.

(go version is 1.13, amd64, gcc version is 7.5.0,
I used following as well and the same error exits:
export CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libstdc++"
CC=/usr/bin/gcc CXX=/usr/bin/g++)

Thanks.
Cheers

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: having the same issue in windows 11